# Approximation of acontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

How to approximate a continuous function on $[-\pi,+\pi]$ which is $2\pi$  periodic by a set of trigonometric polynomials in the sup-norm topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First due to uniform continuity, you can approximate a continuous function $f$ by a piecewise linear function $g$ under supnorm on $[-\pi,\pi]$ (just select a partition $P$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ s.t. $||P||<\delta$, which you can get from the uniform continuity).

Extend $g$ to be $2\pi$ periodic. Since $f$ is Lipschitz on $[-\pi,\pi]$, its Fourier Series uniformly converges to it. Then select large enough $N$, you get a trigonometric polynomial approximation of $g$.

Hence by triangle inequality, you get an approximation of $f$

Comment: Hey @ZHANG is there any special significance of $[-\pi,\pi]$ or $[0,2\pi$] will also do?

Comment: @learningmaths It's OK for $f\in C[0,2\pi]$, since you can define $g(x)=f(x+\pi)$, get an approximation of $g$, say $h(x), x\in [-\pi,\pi]$, then set $h^{'}(t)=h(t-\pi)$ is an approximation of $f$, and it's also a trigonometric polynomial.

Comment: @learningmaths In above comment, by $h^{'}$, I mean a function based on $h$, not the derivative of $h$.